# Attempt to De-Referece a Null Object on Live Chat Transcript

Tags: case

I am trying to write a trigger that updates a field on cases when that case is attached to a Live Chat Transcript. Since Case is a lookup field on the transcript, you add the case to the transcript rather than the other way around. The field I am looking to update is Case Origin(Origin). 
What needs to happen functionally is that the Origin field will retroactively update to 'Live Chat" it is attached to a transcript. The case is automatically added to te transcript at the conclusion of the chat. Here is what I have written sofar:

```
trigger LiveChatOriginUpdate on LiveChatTranscript (after update) {

    List<Case> ChatCases = new List<Case>();


    for (LiveChatTranscript transcript : Trigger.new) {

        if (transcript.CaseId != null) {
            ChatCases.add(transcript.Case);
        }

    }

    for (Case CaseToBeUpdated : ChatCases ) {

        CaseToBeUpdated.Origin = 'Live Chat';  


    }   
    update ChatCases; 


     }
```

The error that I am getting states:

> "System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object:
>   Trigger.LiveChatOriginUpdate: line 24, column 1"
>   -The code throwing the error is:
>       CaseToBeUpdated.Origin = 'Live Chat';

Not quite sure whats going on here because the origin typically has a default value (not null). I have also tried inserting "ChatCases" before making that update but I also receive an error. Any input would be welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't actually have an instance of a `Case` record that you're working with in this context, since this is a trigger on the `LiveChatTranscript` object. The solution is to new up a `Case` record to be used for the update transaction and use the `Id` of the `Case` noted on the `LiveChatTranscript` record in the trigger.

```
trigger LiveChatOriginUpdate on LiveChatTranscript (after update) {

    List<Case> ChatCases = new List<Case>();


    for (LiveChatTranscript transcript : Trigger.new) {

        if (transcript.CaseId != null) {

            // create the record
            // for convenience, set the origin at the same time
            Case caseToUpdate = new Case(Id = transcript.CaseId, Origin = 'Live Chat');

            // add it to the list for later update
            ChatCases.add(caseToUpdate);
        }

    }

    // update the list if there are records to be processed
    if (ChatCases.size() > 0) {
        update ChatCases; 
    }

}
```

Comment: Really helpful feedback. This worked well in test.